# "npm ERR! cb() never called" error after trying other solutions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, eslint

I know this is a well-known error that has been resolved by many people. However, I did every possible solution and was not able to resolve it. These are the following things I did:

1. I deleted node_modules with the command `rm -rf node_modules` as well
   as the package lock. I then proceed to `npm ci`.
2. I did `npm cache clean -- force` before `npm ci`
3. I reinstalled node.
4. My node is running on 14.7 and I can't upgrade due to the nature of my project being locked to that version.
5. I recloned the project from the git repository but still have the same issue.
6. I restarted my PC

Additional Information:

1. I could not `npm run start` my project as well. I'm having the error:

   'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: `react-scripts` may not be included in your `package.json` try (npm install `react-scripts`) or it may be a global package `npm install react-scripts -g` --- I prefer not installing such packages globally, and if you do install it as a local package `npm run start` will call `react-scripts` just fine. --- it may also be a part of `create-react-app` so maybe you should be installing  that instead.  If you want more help you'll probably need to provide your `package.json`.